# Is there a way to remove blue highlighting when clicking on a link in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have three links on my page that are my emails that when you click on them, it is supposed to copy the email to your clipboard. It does this, but for some reason only in Firefox it creates this blue highlight over the link once you click it. Is there any way I can remove this when I click the link? Here is my html, css and javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#open_menu").click(function() {
        $("#menu").css({
            "pointer-events":"auto",
            "display":"flex"
        });
        if($("#menu").hasClass("component-drop_down_menu_hide_animation"))
            {
                $("#menu").removeClass("component-drop_down_menu_hide_animation");
            }
        $("#menu").addClass("component-drop_down_menu_show_animation");
        $("#component-main_content").css({"pointer-events":"none"});
        if($("#component-main_content").hasClass("component-drop_down_menu_close_animation"))
            {
                $("#component-main_content").removeClass("component-drop_down_menu_close_animation");
            }
        $("#component-main_content").addClass("component-drop_down_menu_open_animation");
    });
    $("#close_menu").click(function() {
        $("#menu").css({
            "pointer-events":"none",
            "display":"none"
        });
        if($("#menu").hasClass("component-drop_down_menu_show_animation"))
            {
                $("#menu").removeClass("component-drop_down_menu_show_animation");
            }
        $("#menu").addClass("component-drop_down_menu_hide_animation");
        if($("#component-main_content").hasClass("component-drop_down_menu_open_animation"))
            {
                $("component-main_content").removeClass("component-drop_down_menu_open_animation");
            }
        $("#component-main_content").addClass("component-drop_down_menu_close_animation");
        $("#component-main_content").css({"pointer-events":"auto"});
    });
    $("#green_email_one").click(function() {
        $("#green_email_one").addClass("component-footer_background_color__green_emails_when_clicked");
        var range = document.createRange();
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById('green_email_one'));
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        document.execCommand('copy');
    });
    $("#green_email_two").click(function() {
        $("#green_email_two").addClass("component-footer_background_color__green_emails_when_clicked");
        var range = document.createRange();
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById('green_email_two'));
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        document.execCommand('copy');
    })
    $("#grey_email").click(function() {
        $("#grey_email").addClass("component-footer_background_color__grey_email_when_clicked")
        var range = document.createRange();
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById('grey_email'));
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        document.execCommand('copy');
    })
    $("#drop_down_menu_email").click(function() {
        $("#drop_down_menu_email").addClass("component-drop_down_menu__email_when_clicked");
        var range = document.createRange();
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById('drop_down_menu_email'));
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        document.execCommand('copy');
    })
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p {
    margin: 0;
    color: #34302D;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

p {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

a {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #34302D;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

a:visited {
    color: #86C543;
    border-bottom-color: #86C543;
}

nav a:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 1px;
}

nav {
    line-height: 50px;
}

.component-surrounding_div {
    position: relative;
}

.component-drop_down_menu--variant-modifier {
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 5%;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 90%;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#component-main_content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.component-header__left-div__nav > a {
    font-size: 23px;
    border-bottom: none;
    color: #34302D;
}

.component-header__left-div__nav_active_a {
    color: #86C543 !important;
}

.component-div_margin {
    margin: 5% 5% 110px 5%;
}

#component-div_margin_projects_page {
    margin-bottom: 120px;
}

.component-div_margin__email_color {
    color: #86C543;
}

.component-div_margin_h2_after_description {
    color: #E6E6E6;
}

.component-header_green_bar {
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #86C543;
}

.component-div_margin__header_div {
    display: flex;
}

.component-header__left-div {
    width: 90%;
}

#component-description_div__h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30px
}

.component-header__right-div {
    width: 10%;
}

#component-div_margin__social_p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.component-footer_background_color {
    background-color: #34302D;
    padding: 50px 5% 40px 5%;
}

.component-footer_background_color__email_border_color {
    border-bottom-color: #34302D;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.component-footer_background_color__div {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.component-footer_background_color__first_div {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.component-footer_background_color__h2 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.component-footer_background_color__h2_after_first {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.component-footer_background_color__p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.component-footer_background_color__first_h2_margin {
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.component-footer_background_color__nav {
    line-height: 25px;
}

.component-footer_background_color__a {
    color: #E6E6E6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #34302D;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.component-footer_background_color__a:visited {
    color: #E6E6E6;
    border-bottom-color: #E6E6E6;
}

.component-footer_background_color__green_emails_when_clicked {
    border-bottom-color: #86C543;
}

.component-footer_background_color__grey_email_when_clicked {
    border-bottom-color: #E6E6E6;
}

.component-drop_down_menu__email_when_clicked {
    color: #86C543 !important;
}

.component-footer_background_color__green_emails_when_clicked::selection,
.component-footer_background_color__grey_email_when_clicked::selection,
.component-drop_down_menu__email_when_clicked::selection {
    background-color: transparent;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

.component-drop_down_menu_open_animation {
    animation-name: drop_down_menu_open;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: .5s;
}

.component-drop_down_menu_close_animation {
    animation-name: drop_down_menu_close;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: .5s;
}

.component-drop_down_menu_show_animation {
    animation-name: drop_down_menu_show;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: .3s;
    animation-duration: .5s;
}

.component-drop_down_menu_hide_animation {
    animation-name: drop_down_menu_hide;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: .5s;
}

@keyframes drop_down_menu_show {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes drop_down_menu_hide {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes drop_down_menu_open {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0.01;
    }
}

@keyframes drop_down_menu_close {
    from {
        opacity: 0.01;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!-- This is so viewing website is scaled well on all devices -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- This is where I am getting all my icons from -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
        <!-- Image by fontawesome.com. Here is link to image: https://fontawesome.com/icons/info-circle?style=solid -->
        <link rel="icon" href="Images/info-circle-solid.png">
        <!-- To remove default browser styling -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.0/normalize.css">
        <!-- My style sheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <!-- JQuery -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- My script -->
        <script src="JavaScript/javascript.js"></script>
        <title>About</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Div container to create drop-down menu overlay functionality -->
        <div class="component-surrounding_div">
            <!-- Drop-down menu -->
            <div class="component-drop_down_menu--variant-modifier" id="menu">
                <!-- Navigation -->
                <div class="component-header__left-div">
                    <nav class="component-header__left-div__nav">
                        <a href="index.html" class="component-header__left-div__nav_active_a">About</a>
                        <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" id="drop_down_menu_email">chadwilson959@yahoo.com</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <!-- Exit button -->
                <div class="component-header__right-div">
                    <i class="fas fa-times fa-3x" id="close_menu"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div id="component-main_content">
                <!-- Green Bar -->
                <div class="component-header_green_bar"></div> 
                <header class="component-div_margin">
                    <div class="component-div_margin__header_div">
                        <div class="component-header__left-div">
                            <h1>Hi, I'm Chad.</h1>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Open menu button -->
                        <div class="component-header__right-div">
                            <i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x" id="open_menu"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>
                <!-- Intro section -->
                <div class="component-div_margin">
                    <h2 id="component-description_div__h2">I am an aspiring front-end web developer.</h2>
                    <p>I use my front-end web development skills to create beautiful and efficent websites.</p>
                    <p>I am also knowledgeable with back-end web development but front-end web development is my expertise.</p>
                </div>
                <!-- Projects section -->
                <div class="component-div_margin">
                    <h2 class="component-div_margin_h2_after_description">Projects</h2>
                    <p>Sorry, nothing to show here at the moment except for this website I built.</p>
                    <p>However, I am in the process of developing a prayer application with a group of other developers I worked with last summer during an internship that will soon be deployed!</p>
                </div>
                <!-- Resume section -->
                <div class="component-div_margin">
                    <h2 class="component-div_margin_h2_after_description">Resume</h2>
                    <div>
                        <p>Click the link below to view my resume.</p>
                        <div>
                            <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OZmiZXM1XlSSVFU3O_cojis07KVhB-dL/view?usp=sharing" target="_blank">Resume</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Social media section -->
                <div class="component-div_margin">
                    <h2 class="component-div_margin_h2_after_description">Social</h2>
                    <p id="component-div_margin__social_p">Here are links to my Linkedin and GitHub accounts.</p>
                    <nav>
                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/chad-wilson-b35160b6/" target="_blank">Linkedin</a>
                        <a href="https://github.com/chadwilson20" target="_blank">GitHub</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <!-- Email section -->
                <div class="component-div_margin">
                    <h2 class="component-div_margin_h2_after_description">Contact</h2>
                    <p>Here is my email if you wish to contact me. Click on my email address below to copy the address to your clipboard.</p>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="component-div_margin__email_color" id="green_email_one">chadwilson959@yahoo.com</a>
                </div>
                <!--Footer-->
                <footer class="component-footer_background_color">
                    <div class="component-footer_background_color__first_div">
                        <h2 class="component-footer_background_color__h2 component-footer_background_color__first_h2_margin">Chad Wilson</h2>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="component-div_margin__email_color component-footer_background_color__email_border_color" id="green_email_two">chadwilson959@yahoo.com</a>
                        <p class="component-footer_background_color__a component-footer_background_color__p">I use my front-end web development skills to create beautiful and efficent websites.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="component-footer_background_color__div">
                        <h2 class="component-footer_background_color__h2 component-footer_background_color__h2_after_first">Menu</h2>
                        <nav class="component-footer_background_color__nav">
                            <a href="index.html" class="component-footer_background_color__a">About</a>
                            <a href="projects.html" class="component-footer_background_color__a">Projects</a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div class="component-footer_background_color__div">
                        <h2 class="component-footer_background_color__h2 component-footer_background_color__h2_after_first">Contact</h2>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="component-footer_background_color__a" id="grey_email">chadwilson959@yahoo.com</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="component-footer_background_color__h2 component-footer_background_color__h2_after_first">Social</h2>
                        <nav class="component-footer_background_color__nav">
                            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/chad-wilson-b35160b6/" target="_blank" class="component-footer_background_color__a">Linkedin</a>
                            <a href="https://github.com/chadwilson20" target="_blank" class="component-footer_background_color__a">GitHub</a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if you have trouble finding the links I am talking about. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `it creates this blue highlight` nope, doesn't do that at all

Comment: @JaromandaX It highlights it, not on chrome, but on Firefox

Comment: OK, let me correct myself ... Firefox 62 does NOT, however, Firefox 61 does! (the perils of using the developer edition of Firefox :p )

Comment: after `document.execCommand('copy');` add `selection.removeAllRanges();` - done

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JaromandaX Yup, adding the selection.removeAllRanges() did the trick! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the selection ranges once you're done with the copying:

```js
link.onclick = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var range = document.createRange();
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  range.selectNodeContents(link);
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
  document.execCommand('copy');
  // now clear the selection
  selection.removeAllRanges();
};
```

```html
<a href="#" id="link">hello world</a>
```